# Sum or join rows by criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, sql-update

Suppose I have a table like this:

Table1

```
 EmployeeID   Month          sym      Quantity       V_M       BudjetCode
    222222            1           40          133.35    1214          800000
    222222            2           40         178.50     115           800000
    222222            3           40         150.33     215           800000
    222222            4           40         186.37     315           800000
    222222            5           40         127.38     415           800000
    222222            6           40         153.00     515           800000
    222222            7           40         178.50     615           800000
    222222            7           40          8.50      615         700052015
    222222            8           40         187.00     715          800000
```

And I would like to change this table to:

Table 2

```
EmployeeID    Month          sym      Quantity          V_M           BudjetCode
        222222            1           40          133.35    1214          800000
        222222            2           40         178.50     115           800000
        222222            3           40         150.33     215           800000
        222222            4           40         186.37     315           800000
        222222            5           40         127.38     415           800000
        222222            6           40         161.5      515           800000
        222222            7           40         178.50     615           800000
        222222            8           40         187.00     715          800000
```

How? 
See the row in table 1 where the BudjetCode is unusual?

well, for this row I would like to add the Quantity value (8.5) to the row there V_M is one less than the V_M is the original row (where the budjetCode is 700052015).

In the example, in the original it was 615 so one less is 515 (615 means date 6.15 and 515 means 5.15) and to that I need to add the quantity (8.5 to 153 = 161.5)

I was thinking of "over partition":

```
select [EmployeeID],[Month],[Sym],
sum([Quantity]) 
over (partition by [EmployeeID], [V_M]-1 where???) as b
from table1 
where [Sym] = '40' and [EmployeeID] = 222222
order by [Month]
```

But I don't know how to sum this up usiing the criteria of the budjetCode starts with "700".

comment : Don't to this for the first row.

Update:

```
EmployeeID month Quantity V_M   MS_BudjetCode
22222   1   40  133.35  1214    88888888
22222   2   40  178.50  115 88888888
22222   3   40  150.33  215 88888888
22222   4   40  186.37  315 88888888
22222   5   40  127.38  415 88888888
22222   6   40  153.00  515 88888888
22222   7   40  8.50    615 700000000
22222   7   40  178.50  615 88888888
22222   8   40  187.00  715 88888888
```

Output:

```
22222   2   40  178.50  115 88888888
22222   4   40  186.37  315 88888888
22222   8   40  187.00  715 88888888
22222   3   40  151.33  215 88888888
22222   3   40  151.33  215 88888888
22222   3   40  151.33  215 88888888
22222   3   40  149.33  215 88888888
22222   3   40  149.33  215 88888888
22222   5   40  127.38  415 88888888
22222   6   40  152.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  154.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  152.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  154.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  154.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  152.00  515 88888888
22222   6   40  161.50  515 88888888
22222   7   40  178.50  615 88888888
22222   1   40  133.35  1214    88888888
```

Query:

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeID, t1.Month, t1.sym, 
       t1.Quantity + COALESCE(t2.Quantity, 0), 
       t1.V_M, t1.BudjetCode 
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2 
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID AND t1.V_M = t2.V_M - 100 AND 
     SUBSTRING(t2.BudjetCode,1,3) = '700'
WHERE SUBSTRING(t1.BudjetCode,1,3) <> '700' and sym='40' and EmployeeID = 22222
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a solution, i think we cant simply subtract 1 with month, need to consider january december cases also. i had included that checking also. here budgetcode is distinguished with length, you can change it if needed.

`;WITH CTETable1 AS
(
    SELECT 
        EmployeeID,[Month],sym,
        CASE WHEN LEN(BudjetCode)>6 THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END Quantity,
        CASE WHEN LEN(BudjetCode)>6 THEN 
            (CASE WHEN LEFT(V_M,LEN(V_M)-2)=1 THEN 12 ELSE LEFT(V_M,LEN(V_M)-2)-1 END)*100+ 
            (CASE WHEN LEFT(V_M,LEN(V_M)-2)=1 THEN RIGHT(V_M,2)-1 ELSE RIGHT(V_M,2) END)  ELSE 0 END V_M,
        BudjetCode
    FROM Table1 
)
SELECT 
    T1.EmployeeID,T1.[Month],T1.sym,T1.Quantity+ISNULL(T2.Quantity,0) Quantity,
    T1.V_M,T1.BudjetCode
FROM Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN CTETable1 T2 ON T1.EmployeeID=T2.EmployeeID AND T1.V_M=T2.V_M 
WHERE LEN(T1.BudjetCode)=6`

Comment: Thank you But LEN(BudjetCode)>6  means for the unsusual record?

Comment: And how can I restrict to sym ='40' only?

Comment: you can restrict to sym ='40' by adding in where clause

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using a simple `LEFT JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT t1.EmployeeID, t1.Month, t1.sym, 
       t1.Quantity + COALESCE(t2.Quantity, 0), 
       t1.V_M, t1.BudjetCode 
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 AS t2 
  ON t1.EmployeeID = t2.EmployeeID AND t1.V_M = t2.V_M - 100 AND 
     SUBSTRING(t2.BudjetCode,1,3) = '700'
WHERE SUBSTRING(t1.BudjetCode,1,3) <> '700'
```

The query select all table rows *but* the 'unusual' ones and joins them with 'unusual' rows one day (or is it maybe hour?) ahead. `Quantity` returned is the sum of the value of 'normal' row plus the value of the related 'unusual' row (if such one really exists).

Expression:

```
t1.V_M = t2.V_M - 100
```

implements *one less* relation between `V_M`of `t1` and `t2`. You may change it to suit your actual needs.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e7f4/1)

Comment: Thank's. Any reason why it double the results?

I got : 1  133.35, 178.5, 149.33, 151.33, 186.37, 127.38,152,154,161.5, 178.5, 187.

Comment: @Jordan1200 There must be something different in your real data. Have you checked the demo I made? Can you modify it to include such a case of 'data doubling'?

Comment: Did you run the query on table 1 and got exactly table 2?

Comment: @Jordan1200 Yes I did. Did you check the demo I've setup? It demonstrates exactly this. Let me know if there's something wrong in the demo.

Comment: Hey, I updated my initial post. See there my output please. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jordan1200 Output doesn't match with the input using the query you posted. Check [**here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4638/1)

Comment: That's really odd. I'' check it later and let you know. Can you explain to me what is the purpose of the COALESCE?

Comment: @Jordan1200 I think your actual data does not match the sample data posted here. For `COALESCE` have a look [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). In case `Quantity` is `NULL` it is converted to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Will this solve your problem?

```
DELETE
FROM
table
WHERE BudjetCode='700052015'
```

AND

```
UPDATE table
SET Quantity = (Quantity+8.5)
WHERE Month = 6;
```

Comment: Make sure you include the ID number if there are rows that would have likewise data to the where clauses. That way you don't make changes to more rows than expected.